# Paste not working

Tags: cut-copy-paste, paste

File:

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
```

If I `yyP` on 2222, the system clipboard is pasted in, not 2222 as expected. However, `:reg` shows that 2222 was saved to register `0` and `"`. I expected it to save to th

If I `ddP` on 4444, everything works as expected: That line is deleted and then 4444 is pasted. So, it seems delete is working as expected, but yank is not.

My current solution is to use `delete` then `undo` until I figure out why yanks aren't working.

Notes:

- vim version 8.1
- Windows 10
- _vimrc does *not* have `set clipboard=unnamed`.
- Also, interestingly, delete not only saves to a vim register, but also to the system clipboard. My impression is that this is abnormal, but I do prefer it this way.

Comment: I typed `:set clipboard` in command mode and it said `clipboard=unnamedplus`. I changed it using `:set clipboard=unnamed` and now vim yanks to the system register, and indeed `:set clipboard` returns `unnamed`. However, when I put `set clipboard=unnamed` in my _vimrc file, it doesn't take effect. Vim is still starting with `unnamedplus`. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, editing `_vimrc` in the Vim file wasn't working. From within vim, if I used `:e! $MYVIMRC` to change the file, everything worked out.

I removed `set clipboard=unnamedplus` and the behavior is now back to normal. Whew!